# How to make a query sql Injection safe in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

How can I make this query sql injection safe please?
Will JRequest::getVar ensure that the parameter that is passed is sql injection safe?

```
$product_id = JRequest::getVar('product_id')
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = " select * from #__products where product_id=".$product_id."; ";       
$db->setQuery($query);
$data = $db->loadObjectList();
return $data[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using **getVar** function to access request variables, will ensure that all user data is filtered before it’s used somewhere else (such as in SQL queries).
**getVar** method on the JRequest class automatically filters out the input (unless explicitly told otherwise).

You can also use [quote](http://api.joomla.org/11.4/Joomla-Platform/Database/JDatabase.html#quote) to escape strings before inserting to database

Comment: thank you for your answer, is this sure? Because as I was looking around, someone told me that I should use something like JDatabase::quote to ensure this..

Comment: yea, you can use that also so that strings are escaped before inserting to database

Answer (score 3):

Just as an extension of @Sudhir's answer.

`JRequest` has been depreciated since Joomla! 1.7 and is being progressively removed e.g. [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3.0](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#JRequest). If you intend to keep your component around you may want to migrate your old style `JRequest` calls to [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/JInput_Background_for_Joomla_Platform).